# make border-style ridge look the same on edge, firefox, and chrome

Tags: html, css

[image]

Is there a way to make it look like it does on chrome across all 3 browsers?

The code below...

html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Temp</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers|Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="div-bouncing-arrow" />
    </div> <!-- container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, 
object, iframe, blockquote, pre,
abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.872rem;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h4, p, a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

a:link {
  color: (internal value);
}
a:visited {
  color: (internal value);
}
a:link:active {
  color: (internal value);
}
a:visited:active {
  color: (internal value);
}

h5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.328rem;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.072rem;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
body,
#root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Destkop */
.container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 884px;
    width: 884px;
    height: 20vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #016CA7;
}

.div-bouncing-arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.div-bouncing-arrow::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom: 5px ridge #ffffff;
  border-right: 5px ridge #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -moz-animation: 0.3s ease-out 0.3s infinite alternate bounce-arrow-before;
  -webkit-animation: 0.3s ease-out 0.3s infinite alternate bounce-arrow-before;
  animation: 0.3s ease-out 0.3s infinite alternate bounce-arrow-before;
}

.div-bouncing-arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom: 5px ridge #ffffff;
  border-right: 5px ridge #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -moz-animation: 0.3s ease-out 0.3s infinite alternate bounce-arrow-after;
  -webkit-animation: 0.3s ease-out 0.3s infinite alternate bounce-arrow-after;
  animation: 0.3s ease-out 0.3s infinite alternate bounce-arrow-after;
}

@keyframes bounce-arrow-before {
  from {
    top: 0%;
  }
  to {
    top: 9%;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce-arrow-after {
  from {
    top: 11%;
  }
  to {
    top: 20%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no exact standard definitions for how a browser chooses the contrasting colors for a border of type ridge so I guess that will have to be abandoned in favor of defining colors directly. Have you tried anything else?

Comment: @AHaworth To even get to this point too me many hours. The only thing I can possibly think of is having somehow a combination of divs with box-shadow maybe. Or maybe an svg image with a transparent background.